# Value of input is undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery

SO!

I am trying to learn AJAX. Im trying to take the value of an input box, and place it on a screen. However, when I call jQuery's .val() function, it returns undefined. Can anyone tell me why this is? I have tried literally EVERYTHING.

```
<div class="action-center text-center">     
<div class="input-group input-group-lg">         
<span class="input-group-addon" id="sizing-addon1"><i class="fa fa-user object"></i></span>         
<input type="text" class="form-control" id="id1" placeholder="Username" aria-describedby="sizing-addon1">     
</div>     
<div class="input-group input-group-lg">         
<span class="input-group-addon" id="sizing-addon2"><i class="fa fa-coffee object"></i></span>      
<input type="text" class="form-control object" id="id2" placeholder="Username" aria-describedby="sizing-addon1">   
</div>     
<button class="btn btn-success" id="submit">Submit</button>     
<button class="btn btn-danger remove-action">Remove</button> </div>
```

JS:

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
    $(function()
    {
        var $orders = $('.list-group');
        var $nameFieldGroup = $('#id1');
        var $orderFieldGroup = $('#id2');
        $.ajax({type: 'GET', url: 'test.json', success: function(data)
        {
            $.each(data, function(i, item)
            {
                $orders.append('<li class="list-group-item"><p>Name: '+ item.name + '</p><p>Drink: ' + item.drink +'</p></li>');
            });
        }, error: function()
        {
            alert("AJAX error")
        }});

        $('#submit').on('click', function()
        {
            var order = {name: $nameFieldGroup.val(), drink: $orderFieldGroup.val()};
            $.ajax({type: 'POST', url: 'test.json', data: order, success: function(newOrder)
            {
                $orders.append('<li class="list-group-item"><p>Name: '+ newOrder.name + '</p><p>Drink: ' + newOrder.drink +'</p></li>');
            }});
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: Please edit your question to include the code?

Comment: "Im trying to take the value of an input box, and place it on a screen" — That doesn't actually involve Ajax at all. (But we can't tell what is wrong with code we can't see).

Comment: `$(document).ready(function() {})` and `$(function() { })` do exactly the same thing; you only need one.

Comment: Please do not roll back the edit, your question has nothing to do with AJAX and contains not required text.

Comment: @Gareth why have you removed the html in your edit - that's vital to the question

Comment: it works fine - i've taken the ajax stuff out as thats not the question - https://jsfiddle.net/xqhddqjj/

Comment: @DarrenSweeney rolled back to an earlier revision prior to the HTML being added, sorry!

Answer (score -1):

Are `$('#id1')` and `$('#id2')` are dynamically loaded controls? If they are dynamic controls, then please replace

```
 $nameFieldGroup.val() with $('#id1').val() and $orderFieldGroup.val()  with $('#id2').val()
```

Also I concur the other comments listed under question. Question and code dees not seem to be related.